# How to get VPC subnet ids via terraform_remote_state?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My vpc state file is at dev/vpc/main/terraform.tfstate. I would like to prevision mariaDB using the private subnets in vpc.
I got errors:

Error: Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:

- module.csc_db_sbnet_group.var.db_subnet_group_ids: element: element() may not be used with an empty list in:

${element(data.terraform_remote_state.vpc_subnets_ids.vpc_private_subnets_ids,0)}

MariaDB code (note: MariaDB code has its own terrafrom state file):

```
data_sources.tf: 

data "terraform_remote_state" "vpc_subnets_ids" {
  backend = "s3"

  config {
    bucket = "dev-terraform-state"
    key    = "dev/vpc/main/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-west-2"
  }
}

resources.tf:
module "csc_db_sbnet_group" {
  source               = "modules/rds-subnet-group"
  db_subnet_group_name = "${var.db_subnet_group_name}"
  db_subnet_group_ids  = ["${element(data.terraform_remote_state.vpc_subnets_ids.vpc_private_subnets_ids,0)}", "${element(data.terraform_remote_state.vpc_subnets_ids.vpc_private_subnets_ids,1)}"]
}
```

VPC code:

```
resources.tf:

module "vpc" {
  source = "modules/vpc"

  aws_region   = "${var.region}"
  vpc_tag_name = "${var.vpc_name}"
  vpc_cidr     = "${var.vpccidr}"

  private-subnet-mapping = ["${var.private_az_subnets_cidr}"]
  public-subnet-mapping  = ["${var.public_az_subnets_cidr}"]
}

resource "aws_subnet" "add_private_subnets" {
  count = "${length(var.private-subnet-mapping)}"

  cidr_block        = "${lookup(var.private-subnet-mapping[count.index], "cidr")}"
  vpc_id            = "${module.vpc.vpc_id}"
  availability_zone = "${lookup(var.private-subnet-mapping[count.index], "az")}"

  tags = {
    Name = "${lookup(var.private-subnet-mapping[count.index], "name")}"
    BU   = "${lookup(var.private-subnet-mapping[count.index], "BU")}"
  }
}

outputs.tf
output "vpc_private_subnets_ids" {
  value = ["${aws_subnet.add_private_subnets.*.id}"]
}

output "vpc_private_subnets_cidrs" {
  value = ["${aws_subnet.add_private_subnets.*.cidr_block}"]
}
```

When I provision MariaDB, I would like to use the private subnets provisioned in VPC code. But, it complains,

- module.csc_db_sbnet_group.var.db_subnet_group_ids: element: element() may not be used with an empty list in:

${element(data.terraform_remote_state.vpc_subnets_ids.vpc_private_subnets_ids,0)}

Comment: What version of terraform are you using? And is the `private_subnets_id` output on the root module too?

Comment: Is this 0.11? If this is your module, then what is `aws_subnet.production_private_subnets`?

Comment: Thanks for the question and comment. The terraform version is v0.11.13. I updated the code. See above. But, I got new error. It complains ${element(data.terraform_remote_state.vpc_subnets_ids.vpc_private_subnets_ids,0)} is empty. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Do the outputs exist in the vpc state file? If you added the outputs without doing a plan and apply afterwards they won't be in the state.

Comment: I ran terraform output. I got, vpc_private_subnets_cidrs = [] 

vpc_private_subnets_ids = []
Why the lists are empty? I logon to aws colo. I do see the list of subnets there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added code below for VPC and solved the problem.

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "private_subnet_ids" {
  vpc_id            = "${module.vpc.vpc_id}"
}
data "aws_subnet" "private_subnet" {
  count = "${length(data.aws_subnet_ids.private_subnet_ids.ids)}"
  id    = "${data.aws_subnet_ids.private_subnet_ids.ids[count.index]}"
}
```